# Recursive partitioning tree vs neural network model

Tags: neural-networks, partitioning, recursive-model

I hope this question helps shed some light on trees vs neural models. I recently came across a model tree, or a recursive partitioning model. It is basically a decision tree that has linear regression models trained for every leaf node of this tree. A most prominent example of this method could be the [M5 model](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/1992-Quinlan-AI.pdf) from Quinlan, 1992. Basically what got me here is [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78563/regression-tree-algorithm-with-linear-regression-models-in-each-leaf). I thought about this model and it seemed to me that it is relatively similar to a feed-forward neural network using ReLU as activation functions. I played around a little bit with [this](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/regression.html) nice visualization tool from Karpathy. Try playing around with how only ReLU activations would get joined together to create a nice approximation for the input data.

I was wondering if anyone could explain the main, fundamental differences about what these models can or cannot do; or in what way they are the same/different. All your answers are appreciated!